# react-router-dom link not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v6.2.1. I have following app router

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route element={<DefaultOutlet />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/employees" element={<EmployeeList />} />
        <Route path="/employee/:employeeId" element={<Employee />}/>
        <Route path="/not-found" element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I have following navbar

```
const Header = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
       <Link to={`/employee/${user?.employeeId}`}>MY DATA</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a list of employees and I can visit their profile in '/employee/:employeeId'. Let's say I'm on page '/employee/10' which is some xyz employee's profile page and my profile is on '/employee/11' . When I hit on 'MY DATA' it should redirect me to '/employee/11' but its not happening. Link in the browser's search bar is changing to '/employee/11' but it is not taking me to that page.

Appreciate your help.

### Update

Got resolved after adding employeeId in useEffect dependency array

```
const Employee = () => {
const { employeeId } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {}, [employeeId])  // added employeeId in useEffect dependency array and got resolved the problem
return (
<h1>employees page</h1>
)
```

Comment: Path is getting changed and I'm also reading parameter by useParam. But component is not getting rerendered.

Comment: what is your `Employee` component looks like?

Comment: Have you added `<Outlet/>` inside DefaultOutlet Component ? Check this your code is working as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-keldysh-9b6xl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: why this Route `<Route element={<DefaultOutlet />}>` doesn't have a path?

Comment: Where is the `Header`/navbar rendered in relation to the code snippet(s) you've provided that is rendering the router and routes?